# How to search with spaces and multiple words

Tags: mysql, search

My search module is not effective because I only search one of this fields, I like to implement for example Biogesic Paracetamol combined in query

```
 if ($cat_id != 0) {
      $sqlProducts = "SELECT * FROM product  
        WHERE (PRODUCT_BRANDNAME LIKE '%$searchStr%' OR 
               PRODUCT_GENERIC_NAME LIKE '%$searchStr%') AND 
               CATEGORY_ID = $cat_id LIMIT $start_from,$num_per_page";
    }
```

Comment: So, can you show us HOW you are trying to solve your issue, and not just ask for a solution?

Comment: @Ron didnt he write the code above?

Comment: He wrote a code which is "not effective", but how did he try to solve his "not effective" code? That is what needs to be shown here... He needs to show his effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors that he needs help with and example output that is expected

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Every time I have a problem, I first try to solve it by myself, a number of times, then I read, then I reiterate this few times, and THEN I ask for help. And if I solve the issue myself, THEN I pat myself on the back, and I see that I've learned a lot via this process.. not by simply asking for solutions... That is also the idea of SO! And that is exactly how I advance and know more and more ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
if ($cat_id != 0) {
  $sqlProducts = "SELECT * FROM product  WHERE CONCAT(PRODUCT_BRANDNAME,PRODUCT_GENERIC_NAME) LIKE '%"+$searchStr+"%') AND CATEGORY_ID = $cat_id LIMIT $start_from,$num_per_page";
}
```

Comment: `'%"+$searchStr+"%'` this does not seem correct in PHP